# Why only the cell from the last row is updated?

Tags: php, html

When I am trying to update only one cell in my form-table, only the last row is updated.
Please help me solve the issue and teach me how to update each one of the rows.
Thanks, Shay.

The relevant PHP code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $callid = $_POST['callid'];
    $statusOfWork = $_POST['statusOfWork'];
    $areaNumber = $_POST['areaNumber'];  

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'nitzanpi_calls');

    if (!$connection){
        die("Database connection failed" .mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");

    if($areaNumber == '1'){
        $sql1 = "UPDATE calls SET statusOfWork = '".$statusOfWork."' WHERE areaNumber = '1' AND callid = '".$callid."'";
    }
    elseif($areaNumber == '2'){
        $sql1 = "UPDATE calls SET statusOfWork = '".$statusOfWork."' WHERE areaNumber = '2' AND callid = '".$callid."'";
    }
    elseif($areaNumber == '3'){
        $sql1 = "UPDATE calls SET statusOfWork = '".$statusOfWork."' WHERE areaNumber = '".$areaNumber."' AND callid = '".$callid."'";
    }
    elseif($areaNumber == '4'){
        $sql1 = "UPDATE calls SET statusOfWork = '".$statusOfWork."' WHERE areaNumber = '4' AND callid = '".$callid."'";
    }
    elseif($areaNumber == '5'){
        $sql1 = "UPDATE calls SET statusOfWork = '".$statusOfWork."' WHERE areaNumber = '5' AND callid = '".$callid."'";
    }
    elseif($areaNumber == '6'){
        $sql1 = "UPDATE calls SET statusOfWork = '".$statusOfWork."' WHERE areaNumber = '6' AND callid = '".$callid."'";     
    }

    $query1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);        

    if (!$query1) {
        die ('SQL Error: '. mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}
?>
```

Here the relevant HTML code:

```
   <form  method="post">
 <div class="container" id="callstable">
          <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>  
                 <th class="text-right">#</th>         
                 <th class="text-right">אזור</th>
                 <th class="text-right">כתובת</th>
                 <th class="text-right">סוג קריאה</th>
                 <th class="text-right">מועד אחרון לטיפול</th>          
                 <th class="text-right">סטטוס</th>   
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>                   
              <?php foreach($query as $values): ?>
                <tr>
                  <input type="hidden" name="callid" value="<?php echo $values['callid']?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="areaNumber" value="<?php echo $values['areaNumber']?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="statusOfWork" value="<?php echo $values['statusOfWork']?>">
                  <td class="text-right"><?php echo $values['callid']?> </td> 
                  <td class="text-right"><?php echo $values['areaNumber']?> </td> 
                  <td class="text-right"><?php echo $values['streetName'] ?> <?php echo $values['streetNumber']?> </td>
                  <td class="text-right"><?php echo $values['callType']?> </td>
                  <td class="text-right"><?php echo $values['timeRemain']?> </td>
                  <td class="text-right">
                  <select name="statusOfWork">                       
                    <option value="<?php echo $values['statusOfWork']?>">
                        <?php echo $values['statusOfWork']?> </option>
                    <option value="פתוח">פתוח</option>
                    <option value="בטיפול">בטיפול</option>
                    <option value="סיום עבודה">סיום עבודה</option>
                    <option value="סגור">סגור</option> </select>
                  </td>
                  <td><button type="button" onclick="window.open('../.php?id=<?php echo $values['callid']?>', '_blank')">צפה במפה</button></td> 
                  <td><button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">עדכן</button></td>
                </tr>
              <?php endforeach ?>
              </tbody> 
            </table>
  </div>

  </form>
```

Comment: make space between 'else if' may be syntax error

Comment: @HarshMittal That is in fact [not](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) an error :-)

Answer (score 1):

In every table row you have the same named hidden input fields, on submitting the form only the values of the last unique named elements are submitted.

You can give the hidden fields unique names with the callid...

```
<input type="hidden" name="areaNumber_<?php echo $values['callid']?>" value="<?php echo $values['areaNumber']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="statusOfWork_<?php echo $values['callid']?>" value="<?php echo $values['statusOfWork']?>">
```

... and also change the value of the submit button to the callid.

On the PHP side you now can access the values with

```
$callid = $_POST['submit'];
$statusOfWork = $_POST['statusOfWork_'.$callid];
$areaNumber = $_POST['areaNumber_'.$callid];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.
One question, what do you mean by "change the value of the submit button to the callid"?

Comment: `<td><button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">עדכן</button></td>` => `<td><button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $values['callid']?>">עדכן</button></td>` so you identify the button which is used to submit the form and know the fields with the data to use.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is in your HTML form. Becuase you are using a foreach to create multiple copies of field with the same name, only the last field with the same name is being sent to your PHP file. You just need to add [] after each field name so that values from all the fields are stored in an array.

```
<input type="hidden" name="callid[]" value="<?php echo $values['callid']?>">
```

of you could also add the callid as a key for each row.

```
<input type="hidden" name="areaNumber[<?php echo $values['callid']?>]" value="<?php echo $values['areaNumber']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="statusOfWork[<?php echo $values['callid']?>]" value="<?php echo $values['statusOfWork']?>">
```

This will put all the form data into an array like:

```
Array
(
    [callid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [areaNumber] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [statusOfWork] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

You will then need to modify your PHP code accordingly. Also please note that your unescaped SQL statements are prone to injection in their current form and that [procedural mysql fucntions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5 It's recommended to use the object-oriented [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent SQL Injection. If you want to stick with procedural style then use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to escape your values.

You also shouldn't be using the mysql 'root' user for queries. It's best to create another user with privileges to the functions that are needed to be performed.

A very rough example of object oriented [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) version of you code is:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $callid = $_POST['callid'];
    $statusOfWork = $_POST['statusOfWork'];
    $areaNumbers = $_POST['areaNumber'];  

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    foreach($areaNumers as $key => $areaNumer) {

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE calls SET statusOfWork = ? WHERE areaNumber = ? AND callid = ?")) {
        /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $statusOfWork[$key]);
    $stmt->bind_param("a", $areaNumer);
    $stmt->bind_param("c", $callid[$key]);

        /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();  
          $stmt->close();        
        }

        /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();

    }
```